# How display 3 words from difference table columns to a single listview column using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm finding a way to display 3 data (surname,Firstname,Mi) from a database to a single column of a listview, so that the name column will be composed of the whole name of a person instead of just the surname.

```
    Try
        DatabaseConnection()
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Query = "select * from dtr_database.dtr_entries"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT iddtr_entries, dtr_entry_number, dtr_entry_lname, dtr_entry_fname, dtr_entry_mi FROM dtr_entries"
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader
        If Reader.HasRows Then
            Do While Reader.Read()
                Dim item As New ListViewItem
                item.Text = Reader("iddtr_entries")
                item.SubItems.Add(Reader("dtr_entry_number"))
                item.SubItems.Add(Reader("dtr_entry_lname"))
                item.SubItems.Add(Reader("dtr_entry_fname"))
                item.SubItems.Add(Reader("dtr_entry_mi"))
                ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox("No Records Found")
        End If
        Reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

So, i want to combine lname,fname and mi in a column of a listview, i've tried this code below but it doesn't work

```
    item.SubItems.Add(Reader("dtr_entry_lname" & "," & "dtr_entry_fname" & "," & "dtr_entry_mi"))
```

What am i doing wrong here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you need to use `Reader` for each column:

```
item.SubItems.Add(Reader("dtr_entry_lname") & "," & _
  Reader("dtr_entry_fname") & "," & Reader("dtr_entry_mi"))
```